# File format not recognized when run objdump in binutils

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, gnu, objdump

There is a .a lib in iOS project. I want to see the methods name in it, so I installed binutils on Mac. But when I run objdump [-h] xxx.a. It says:

"File format not recognized".

So, what format does objdump supports? And how can I see the methods in that .a lib without using objdump?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several tools to this.

1. [strings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/strings.1.html) tool.
2. [nm](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/nm.1.html) tool
3. [otool](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/otool.1.html)
4. For Objective C code, use [class dump](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/)

Comment: Thanks Rahul, the strings works. but why it works? I tried dumpbin on windows, not work.

Comment: Read the documentation. All have there specific purpose and using style. I never tried dumpbin.

Comment: None of the links in the answer work.